# UnParse a string into an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, arrays

I'm trying to unparse a string into an array, here is my code:

**EDIT: I've found a bit more information.**

```
startTimeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
NSString *tmpStartTimeString = [[tempItems objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"temp_start_time"];
startTimeArray = (NSMutableArray *)[tmpStartTimeString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"|"]];

[test3 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [startTimeArray count]]];
```

The 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' is deceiving, this is not where the problem is. The code above outputs the following details to the console:

UILable Test3 contains a 2 and the output from the array is as follows:
Start Time: 2010-09-30 16:19:39
Start Time: 2010-09-30 16:19:43

At this point my array has values, so I then try to do the following:

```
startDateTime = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *strStartDateTime = [formatter stringFromDate:startDateTime];
[formatter release];

[startTimeArray addObject:strStartDateTime];
```

and this results in the following error:

-[__NSCFType addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x193370

I can see from Debugger, that strStartDateTime has a valid value.

Any thoughts ?

Regards,
Stephen

Comment: Stephen: When asking questions, please be a little clearer. "Falls over" isn't helpful here-- what happens exactly? What have you looked at in the debugger, and what have you ruled out?

Comment: sorry, I've put in more detail now.

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried the standard debugging tricks, such as separating out the string generation to see if the problem is there? Are you sure `test3` is a valid pointer? Are you sure `startTimeArray` contains what you expect it to? etc. You can step through these lines with Xcode, or use the GDB command line to print out the state of objects.

Comment: (Also, this is not likely to be your problem, but you can't cast an `NSArray` to an `NSMutableArray` like that and expect it to just magically become mutable-- that's dangerous and could lead to a crash somewhere later, although probably not where you're seeing it.)

Comment: Is there any other code where the space is (before the last line)? If there is, you might need to retain the array returned by componentsSeperatedByString. And you __definitely__ don't want to cast it. That's asking for trouble. And you don't need the line `startTimeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` - it's doing absolutely nothing useful - delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not retaining the returned array. Try this :

```
NSString *tmpStartTimeString = [[tempItems objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"temp_start_time"];
startTimeArray = [[tmpStartTimeString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"|"]] retain];

[test3 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [startTimeArray count]]];
```

PS If you definitely need it to be a mutable array, try this :

```
NSString *tmpStartTimeString = [[tempItems objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"temp_start_time"];
NSArray *tempArray = [tmpStartTimeString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"|"]];
startTimeArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArray] retain];

[test3 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [startTimeArray count]]];
```

Comment: Thanks Dean, it was the retain I was missing.